# Terminal - don't require password for shell script to run

Tags: terminal, bash, password, command-line

I am running Yosemite 10.10.5 and I have a shell script which I want to use to toggle whether my wifi connections run through tor or not. This uses the `networksetup` a couple of times and so asks for my password each time I run or cancel it.

Is there a way to make a shell script run without requiring my password each time?

Thanks!

Comment: You can edit the `sudoers` file to give your user access to `networksetup` without requiring a password. Is `networksetup`  the only command requiring `sudo`?

Comment: yep. would you mind elaborating on what and how to edit?

Comment: Need to get in front of a Mac first to make sure I get it right, stay tuned :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a rule to the `/etc/sudoers` file to give your user access rights to `networksetup` without a password.

1. Note the user name of the user account which should be allowed to run the command (you can get the user name by running `whoami` in Terminal)
2. Log in as an admin user
3. Open Terminal
4. `VISUAL=nano sudo visudo` - opens the sudoers file in a kind of friendly editor
5. Jump to the bottom
6. Add

   ```
   USERID-FROM-STEP1 ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/networksetup
   ```

   followed by an empty line(!)
7. Save and quit

You should now be able to run `networksetup` as the user from step 1 without a password prompt by simply entering `sudo networksetup`.

Comment: what if the user is just me? would it be the name of my home directory then?

Comment: @river_jones To get your proper userid just enter `whoami` in the Terminal.  Usually (but not necessarily since you may have renamed your user folder or your user previously) it's the same name as your home folder in /Users.

Comment: On an unrelated note, I was just curious and replaced `nano` with `subl` (I use sublime for development) and this just opened a new blank file (like `touch`). Why is it that `nano` opens the "correct" /etc/subdoers.tmp` but `subl` doesn't?

Comment: Btw, I didn't realize that as an admin I could just add `sudo` to my `networksetup` calls and it's sufficient to suppress password confirmation. But this is useful for allowing the same for non-admin's. Thanks for your time and help!